# How to encode/decode MVC (Multiview video coding) video?

Tags: video-encoding, codec, decoding

I've been playing around with 3d video and heard about the MVC codec as a better way of encoding 3d video. I've found Nokia's MVC software (http://research.nokia.com/page/4988) but it hangs after trying to encode my videos after a while. Does anyone know of any other alternatives or any resources for that particular codec?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JVT's encoder JMVC for research purposes. It's not so efficient. The software manual is here: http://mvclab.googlecode.com/files/SoftwareManual.doc

In order to download this software, you have to install a CVS client, such as WinCVS. After that you may enter the CVS access parameters as below or you can enter the two commands into a command line CVS client

- authentication:  pserver
- host address:    garcon.ient.rwth-aachen.de
- path:    /cvs/jvt
- user name:   jvtuser
- password:    jvt.Amd.2
- module name: jmvc

  ```
  cvs –d :pserver:jvtuser:jvt.Amd.2@garcon.ient.rwth-aachen.de:/cvs/jvt login
  cvs –d :pserver:jvtuser@garcon.ient.rwth-aachen.de:/cvs/jvt checkout jmvc
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The Intel Media SDK supports MVC encoding: http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/media-sdk